# Is there anyway to open an Android application and do something like post a post on FB

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I try to create a Android App that integration with Bixby.Is there anyway to do like this

Hello Bixby -> Open my application and do stuff ( just like open fb and post some post)

I tryed to find but cant find anything bout this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is `app-launch`.

You would model your capsule to reach a `result-view` where you have defined the `payload-mapper` or `payload-uri` to provide your app with the necessary information from the conversation leading up to opening the app.

You can find more information about `app-launch` [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch)